# ActiveMQ 5.14 performance testing using jmeter on Cloud - EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, activemq-classic

I have 4 Amazon EC2 instances. One instance works as a publisher, Another instance works as a consumer and remaining two instances works as a broker in network Mode.

I want to do performance testing of ActiveMQ broker using Jmeter for which i am using client server mode of Jmeter. Servers will be publisher and Consumer and client will be any local machine from which i will send the test plan which will be executed by servers.

Issues :

1. How to send the Jmeter test plan with proper port forwarding from client (local machine) to servers (publisher , consumers).
2. How to connect from one EC2 instance (Publisher/Consumer) to another EC2 instance (broker) using Jmeter.

Please let me know if anyone have an experience on same or any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the above issues so posting an answer:

**For Issue 1**, Please check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-port-forwarding-set-up-load-testing-on-compute-engine/) link which describes how to do port configuration for client server mode of Jmeter.
     After this step, Start your Jmeter with below command for windows / linux.

For client(Local) : jmeter.bat -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
For server(Remote) : ./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1

You can also create SSH tunnel using below command on local machine to see the web console of activemq broker which is working on EC2 instance.

ssh -i brokerkey.pem -L 8161:127.0.0.1:8161 username@instance-ip

**For Issue 2**, we need to use private IP of EC2 instance in providerUrl to connect to broker.

Hope this helps.